# Coloring of another special graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring

Not much time ago I asked about the chromatic polynomial and the chromatic number of a certain graph whose edges were "induced" by an equivalence relation between its vertices. In this case, I have a similar graph, but with different properties:

> In the graph $G$, the vertices are the pairs $(a,b)$, where $a,b \in \{ 1 \dots 8\}$. Two vertices $(a,b), (a',b')$ are connected iff $a + b = a' + b'$. Find the number of components of $G$, the chromatic polynomial and the chromatic number

In this case, I did the following:

To count the number of connected compontents of the graph (i.e., the number of "pieces"), it is as simple as counting how many possible sums are using two numbers of the set $\{ 1 \dots 8\}$, without order. The set of possible sums are $\{ 2 \dots 16\}$, and hence there are $15$ connected components. Since the relation $(a,b) R (a',b') \Leftrightarrow a + b = a' + b'$ is an equivalence one, each of the connected compontents is a $K_i$, where $i \in \{ 2 \dots 16\}$ and $K_i$ is the complete graph of $i$ vertices. The chromatic polynomial is $p_G(x) = \prod_{i = 2}^{16} p_{K_i}(x)$ ($p_{K_i}(x)$ is the chromatic polynomial of the complete graph of $i$ vertices), and the minimum number of colours to use to create a correct coloration of the graph is then $\chi(G) = 16$.

Is this right?

Comment: Generally yes, but the number of vertices inside the cliques is wrong. For example there is no component which is a $K_{16}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the number of pairs that sum $i$ isn't $i$. For example, for $8$, there are $7$ pairs, and for $4$ there are $3$, so it would be a $K_3$, not a $K_4$. Good point, I'll take it into account. However, it is true that it is some $K_j$, right?

Comment: Yes, only the sizes are wrong.